# Framingham risk score as dependent variable in regression analysis

Tags: regression

[I hope this is the correct place to ask this - it might be too applied, so any suggestion on where else to ask are welcome.]

I would like to investigate the association between a certain exposure (an environmental pollutant) is associated with cardio-vascular disease risk. It is of course possible to investigate the associations with the usual risk markers such as blood pressure and blood lipids - but independently they are not a good predictor of overall risk.

My idea was therefore to use a risk-prediction score (e.g. the Framingham Score). This is usually calculate from a number of different risk factors, e.g. blood lipids and blood pressure, but also age and sex. I could therefore use a model as follows (very simplified):

```
CVD-risk <- a + a1 x age + a2 x blood pressure + a3 x cholesterol + ...
```

and then investigate

```
CVD-Risk ~ exposure
```

However: exposure is also affected by age (older people tend to be less exposed), so age acts as a confounder. When I include age in the model:

```
CVD-Risk ~ exposure + age
```

I have age on both sides of the term, which seems to be wrong. Is there any way how this could be resolved, or am I missing something very obvious here?

Thank you!

Comment: exposure is not clear. may define. whar is  confounding here ?

Comment: It's an environmental pollutant - being active outside tends to increase exposure, hence there is overall reduced exposure with increasing age.

Comment: Framingham Score is  a combined estimate. You need another indepedent measure of CVD risk if you want an application of regression model using different component variables. Age is a  surrogate measure for higher/lower exposure.

Comment: It is - it's far from perfect, but it combines the different risk markers, and this is what I 'm looking for.

Comment: Not clear to me ! Please edit your question.

Comment: Framingham (or other scores) combine several risk markers into a single risk score - and this is what I need. Since age & sex are probably the most important risk factors, they have to be included - but this causes the above problem  (I think age is a confounder as it affects both, exposure and risk - it's not just a surrogate marker.)

Comment: age affects risk through the exposure.